# Bibliography for each chapter with embedded system (no .bib-files please)

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to have a separate bibliography at the end of each chapter of a latex book (`\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}`). Each chapter is contained in a separate .tex-file, and each is `\include`d from the "main.tex"-file. I'm coordinating the work of 13 authors through a git-repository, I have helped them to set up their latex environments, and for some of them its the first time they even use latex. In my opinion the embedded bibliography system is much easier to use than the bib-file-system.

I like to use IEEE style, the first reference in each chapter should be [1], the second [2], and at the end of each chapter there should be a bibliography section. There seem to be multiple latex packages for this purpose: biblatex, bibunits, etc. However, can I also use the embedded system for this? I mean, without all these bib-files? It's a small project, and each chapter will only contain 1-5 references; I think there is really no need for a separate bib-file. Separate bib-files also make the build-process more complicated.

The reason I don't want to use bib-files are this:
Option 1 would be to use a separate bib-file per chapter. The build-process then essentially becomes latex+biblatex(chapter1)+biblatex(chapter2)+biblatex(chapter3)+biblatex(chapter4)+biblatex(chapter5)+biblatex(chapter6)+...+latex+latex. I would have to create a make file to automate it, and then helping each of 13 authors to set up the build process so they can continue working.
Option 2 would be one bib-file for all authors together. How would I prevent all kinds of merge and naming conflicts? Yeah, it's possible, but is it worth it?
=> therefore I prefer the embedded system. Is this possible?

Comment: The [build-in](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References) way is the manual way. So the answer is fairly simple: Yes, possible. But you have to do everything by hand.

Comment: chapterbib should work. But you won't get "IEEE style" automatically. The formatting must be done by the authors. And don't confuse bibtex and biblatex.

Comment: @Johannes_B: how do I use multiple bibliographies then? `\begin{refsection}` doesn't work with the embedded system. And the wikibook-page says nothing about multiple bibliographies. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks! this just works, with no additional setup or build steps necessary. I just added a `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}` to the top of my `main.tex` file.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Bibliographies_per_Section_or_Chapter or https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References (at the bottom).

Comment: To be honest, i have no clue what you are really doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package chapterbib. E.g.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\end{document}
```

where the chapters contains thebibliography environments:

```
\cite{doody}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{doody} blblbl

\end{thebibliography}
```

chapterbib will ensure that you don't get problems if an entry is used in more than one chapter.
The formatting and sorting of the entries must be done manually.